# ValueError: Argument 'url' got value 'www.google.com' that cannot be converted to None in Ubuntu OS but not in windows

Tags: selenium, robotframework

For this Test case i am getting below error **"ValueError: Argument 'url' got value 'www.google.com' that cannot be converted to None."** in Ubuntu OS but not in windows

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           OperatingSystem 
*** Variables ***
${Browser}        FF
*** Test Cases ***
Open_browser    www.google.com   ${Browser}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           OperatingSystem 
*** Variables ***
${Browser}   FF
*** Test Cases ***
test
    Open_browser    https://www.google.com  ${Browser}
```

your robot file itself is wrong , you should provide a test name and also provide https://

Answer (score 1):

**I have faced the same issue.**
You need to setup again.
Uninstall Python, and IDE
Again install Python, Robot-Framework, and Selenium.
Set the Python path and web driver path
Now restart the System.
In My case, it is working fine by following these steps.

Answer (score 1):

Download lower version of robotframework

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).